# Import salesforce object data into data extension email is not visible in All subscriber list

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have Imported salesforce data by using Import activity. I can see the data in the data extension but i am not able to see data in data extension but that subscriber is not visible. How much time it will take to populate data into all subscriber list or will a email need to sent out to make it available under all subscriber list.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

If you import data into a Sendable data extension, then no subscriber will be created until you execute a send. When executing a send the following will happen:

If the subscriber already exists in All subscribers then the send will be added to the history of that Subscriber.

If the subscriber doens´t then the subscriber is created with the Subscriber key and email address you have in the Data Extension. No other Subscriber attributes will be filled with data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

1. The target Data Extension is a sendable DE
2. The DE contains one Email Address field (and only one)
3. You have set the corresponding DE field to match Subscribers on Subscriber Key (as your Subscriber relationship)

...then when you send an email to the DE, the Subscribers will automatically be added to the All Subscribers list.

Comment: The Data extension is not sendable. We are using salesforce reports to send emails to the contacts.

Comment: If you are using a Salesforce report to send emails, then why are you importing the data into a DE in the first place? From a Guided Send you can simply select the Salesforce Report (providing that the report contains a Salesforce Lead ID and / or Contact ID) without requiring the report to be imported into a DE.

Comment: Hi Eliot, I haven't structured my question properly sorry for that. We are using Salesforce object(Subscription) Import to import data to data extension. Before sending emails via salesforce reports we have query's will validate the associated subscpition and the email needs to send out. We are not saving the reports data into data extension . For this process can i see subscriber in all subscriber or i can only see them once the email is sent out.

Comment: Thanks Eliot for your response. I am able to see the subscriber in all subscriber list only when the email is sent from salesforce report.

Comment: No problem, that's the expected behavior.